# How safe is the data stored in Session

Tags: c#

I'm considering using the Session variables to store the Connectionstring for a particular user in a Application. Is it safe enough to store this in the Session variables?

Comment: Are you referring to an NHibernate `ISession`? If so, you should tag your question with `nhibernate`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The session variables never leaves the server, the browser only gets a cookie with an id. That makes it no less safe than having the connection string in a .config-file.
But I have to admit that it sounds kind of odd to keep connection strings in session variables.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the session state is stored on the server side, and a secure hash/key is stored in the client's cookie so the server knows which session to use.

Session cookies can be stolen, for example through cookie stealing or session fixation etc, but the actual connection string will be safe.

Answer (score 0):

using a diffrent connection string for evry user, will kill your DB rather quickly

Comment: the problem I want to solve is that I have numerous clients using the same IIS site but the company that a specific client belongs to have a SQL database that only they will use. Today I have one IIS site for each Company but that is not a good solutions since they are all the same except for the connection string in the web.config file